# XSLT Multiple templates with same match

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation

I'm currently stuck on applying multiple xsl:template with the same match for an element. The example below shows the problem.

Does anyone knows a XSL template that creates the expected output using two "template match"s? For technical reasons it's not possible to put the two "template" elements together.

Input

```
<root>
    <elem>123.45</elem>
    <elem>789.12</elem>
</root>
```

XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:decimal-format name="de" decimal-separator="," grouping-separator="."/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/root/elem">
        <xsl:element name="renamed">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/root/elem">
        <xsl:element name="elem">
            <xsl:value-of select="format-number(.,'#.##0,0000','de')" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<root>
    <elem>123,4500</elem>
    <elem>789,1200</elem>
</root>
```

Expected output:

```
<root>
    <renamed>123,4500</renamed>
    <renamed>789,1200</renamed>
</root>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Having two templates of the same priority that match the same node is an error according to the XSLT specification, and:

> if [the processor] does not signal the error, it must recover by choosing, from amongst the matching template rules that are left, the one that occurs last in the stylesheet. ([source](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#conflict))

That is why the second template wins.

If you want to factor out the number formatting as a re-usable component I'd consider a *named template*

```
<xsl:template name="format">
  <xsl:value-of select="format-number(.,'#.##0,0000','de')" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/root/elem">
  <renamed>
    <xsl:call-template name="format" />
  </renamed>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally you would use "mode" to process the same node with different templates. That I think you do not need in your case. If you apply this XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:decimal-format name="de" decimal-separator="," grouping-separator="."/>


<xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
    <xsl:apply-templates />
    </root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/root/elem">
    <xsl:element name="renamed">
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(.,'#.##0,0000','de')" />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

to your source XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
 <elem>123.45</elem>
 <elem>789.12</elem>
</root>
```

you get this output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
 <renamed>123,4500</renamed>
 <renamed>789,1200</renamed>
</root>
```

Comment: Your solution does use one "template" element. I need one that uses two "template" elements for "/root/elem": One that does the number format and another that renames the element.

Comment: Hello weeman, I always stick with KISS (Keep it simple and stupid). So why would you wanna use 2 templates if you can achieve everything with only 1 template?? Best regards, Peter. PS: you can try playing with "modes"